# connecting ec2 instance through filezilla

Tags: amazon-ec2, filezilla

How can i connect to my ec2 instance through filezilla..?

thanks

Comment: http://www.cybersprocket.com/2009/tips-tricks/sftp-tips-tricks/comment-page-1/

Comment: see http://lzw-programmingjourney.blogspot.com/2011/12/set-up-ftp-server-on-amazon-aws-ec2.html for details.

Comment: Follow step by step instructions in this video tutorial http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to open the proper ports (probably 21) on the security group you used to launch your instance. After that, you have to open that port on the instance as well if it's not already open.

Comment: Which one? Open the instance port (by editing your firewall rules) or edit the security group?

Comment: Open the port by editing the firewall rules?

Comment: That depends on the OS and the firewall software used. I guess, by now there is a lot of stuff about filezilla on Serverfault, for example: http://serverfault.com/questions/267193/setting-an-ftp-server-access-on-ec2-filezilla-client-stucks-winscp-rules